# How do I format as code after a list?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting

If you have a list before you try to write code, your code doesn't get styled.

Am I doing something wrong?

- Here's an example
- Second item

  code->this.doesnt(work.at_all)

Comment: You need *8* whitespaces instead of *4* ;).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the suggested method mentioned in [@Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded)'s [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298641/3049655) if you want to format as code *in* the last item of the list.

If you want to format as code *outside* the list, insert a comment between the last item of the list and the code. Like:

- List item 1
- List item 2

```
code
```

Markdown for this example:

```
 - List item 1
 - List item 2

<!-- Comment inserted to render code *outside* the list -->

    code
```

You can also use an empty comment, i.e, `<!---->`

Comment: You can also use `</>` or `</` (not sure if the second one would cause more issues in some cases, though)

Comment: @Rob Are those valid HTML comments? I remember one time when I thought that `<!>` is a valid HTML comment and used it when required and the parser once got confused and misinterpreted stuff.

Comment: This doesn't indent the code section as if it was part of the list item.

Comment: @mins Yes, it doesn't. Check out [@Oded's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298641/3049655) if you want the codeblock as part of the list item

Answer (score 20):

For code in lists to be interpreted *as* code, it needs to be indented 4 spaces further to the list indentation.

- Here's an example
- Second item

  ```
  code->this.does(work.just_fine)
  ```

This is also noted in the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) for advanced lists (pretty much the very last line of that).

Comment: That way the code is visually associated to the last item (the code starts at the baseline of the item, not the baseline of text). What if I want to add code after the list, but don't want it to "belong" to the last item? I used to insert a line containing only e.g. a dot, and then add the code, but this isn't really nice either.