# Two separated code block after each other

Tags: support, code-formatting

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31754459/2625561

I want to separate those codes, so that the site can highlight the JS. Is there a way for it? I know if I type a word bettween the two blocks it works, but that is not really needed here.

Comment: You can put an html comment between the two, otherwise I'm not sure how. Also, consider adding a little bit of explanation to your answer to take it from "an answer" to "a good answer."

Comment: BTW, the answer you've linked is of very low quality. Does not deserve downvote, but really can use some editing to remove "try this" and replace it with explanation of a fix.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True, but I was tried, and I didn't know what I should explain, it was very simple.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298640/2564301

Comment: Explain what the differences between your code and the OP's code is. A handy tool I sometimes use is [diffchecker.com](https://www.diffchecker.com/diff), but any diff tool will work. Actually look at the differences and explain why you have changed what you have changed and why that fixes the problem without introducing new problems.

Comment: I use plain text in between blocks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Put an empty HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) or a [syntax highlighter hint](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) (`<!-- language: lang-html -->`) between the code blocks. Like so:

```
    Code here

<!-- -->

    Code here
```

Which will render as

```
Code here
```

```
Code here
```

---

Note: `<!>` and `<!-->` also work for now, but they are not valid HTML comments and the system could change eventually and make these not work.

Comment: `<!>` works for me.

Comment: @Normal, you're abusing the regex syntax highlighting is using. Soon, it will change, and your hack will break.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Posts are converted into HTML upon submission, and are not re-rendered unless edited.

Comment: @Normal, I was actually referring to your [*`<!>` works for me* comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300572/two-separated-code-block-after-each-other#comment227677_300573). I believe you should still try to match actual HTML comments, nothing more.

Comment: Thanks, though there should be a non-hackly variant. Like 3 emptry lines that doesn't contain spaces or tabs.

Comment: @klenium I always use syntax highlighter hints in order to highlight the code blocks correctly, so I never notice the problem. Doing it that way is not hacky.

Comment: In other words, `<!-- language: lang-js -->` instead of `<!-- -->`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's not really about comments; instead of exclamation point, `<z>` or `<blah>` could be used to the same effect. The processor removes all HTML-like tags that are not whitelisted HTML tags, just as it removed Tiny Giant's `<!-- -->` above. (There is no actual HTML comment in the rendered page.) We are not posting in hand-rolled HTML here...

Comment: _"`<!-->` also work for now, but they are not valid HTML comments"_ Huh, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

There are ways around it as shown by others but I like to give some kind of headers when they aren't the same file/code

```
Try this:
```

**html**

```
<div data-fruit="pear">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).parent().attr("data-fruit");
});
```

Besides, a little bit of text and possibly explanation never hurts an answer ;)

Comment: I don't like that. It's clear which language the codes are. If I write additional info, that's in the top of my answer.

Comment: I think those words are noise and the posts flow much better without them

Comment: It is clear what they are but breaks it up and makes it look a little nicer, imo.

Comment: @TinyGiant headers which clearly make code sections stand out and makes it more obvious what they are is hardly noise. Sure they are short snippets in this example but, especially larger snippets, could benefit from it. For example, if you have two java files, separating them and making it clear which is which is much nicer.

Comment: Well, if the header actually has useful information, I don't see how Tiny Giant's objection would apply at all. But if one says HTML, and the other JS, they are superfluous.

Comment: @Deduplicator again, maybe in this situation but, like the main site, these posts shouldn't just satisfy one particular instance (at least on most occasions). So my example in the previous comment (and there could be many other examples) is a valid point, imo.

Comment: Despite using "try this" (usually used with one character change to OP's code without any explanation) as sample of good answer :). I really think there is no case when code sample does not deserve at least half line of comment. Many visitors are not able to correctly guess where code should go - so something like "js (in script block *after* above HTML)" or similar explanations are very welcome. Also note that many languages have similar syntax C#/JS mix can be very confusing...

Comment: My two cents: thus far I only used the `<!-- -->` trick with a code sample immediately followed by a REPL demonstration of the same code. In such cases, I feel that headers would add no useful information, as the relation of the blocks to each other is very obvious. However, I agree that in the more common case of separate but related code samples, as in this answer, it is better to have some text between them.

Answer (score 6):

There's also the `Javascript/HTML/CSS snippet` editor button (the 7th, looking like `<>`), producing:

```js
$("a").click(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).parent().attr("data-fruit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-fruit="pear">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put an [horizontal rule](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#horizontal-rules) between them:

```
<div data-fruit="pear">
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

---

```
$("a").click(function() {
    var fruit = $(this).parent().attr("data-fruit");
});
```