# Code block formatting looks OK in preview, wrong in main display

Tags: bug, formatting

**Note**: The problem looks similar [to this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298640/how-do-i-format-as-code-after-a-list) and was indeed closed as a duplicate, but in that question the formatting in the preview is also wrong; here the preview is displayed correctly, but after publish it is wrong, so there seems to be a difference between the Markdown JavaScript for preview and for display.

[This question here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65350924/1) - let's see if I can reproduce here too:

1.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
{
 ans+=mp[A[i]+B[j]]; // did this because, if A[i]+B[j] doesn't exist, mp[A[i]+B[j]]=0.
}
```

2. for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
   auto it=mp.find(A[i]+B[j]);
   if(it!=mp.end())
   ans+=mp[A[i]+B[j]];
   }

This looks fine in preview or if you edit, but the second code block doesn't get formatted on display.

Comment: Have you tried GitHub code blocks? Might be a temporary fix

Comment: @andrewtweber Indeed, that does fix it.

Comment: If you want a proper code block and a proper numeration, then you need 8 whitespaces not just 4.

Comment: @Tom This is slightly different as the preview on editing looks OK here, but it's mucked up on publish - the linked example looks wrong on preview too.

Comment: The same thing happened with a post that I edited a few days ago. Good preview, bad published version. It also involved code blocks in a list.